# Webview slow to load

Tags: android

I have a webview followed by 3 buttons. The text that fills the webview and the text for each button is pulled from an sqlite db then each view is set. When the intent opens the buttons are set but the webview is empty then loads a split second later.

Is there something I can do to change this?

Comment: You can show a loading indicator while your content loads ;)

Comment: Is the text for webview dynamic? If it is fixed text, you can try to store it into a file and load it using loadData(). Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a similar problem posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573850/webview-slow-on-loading-content) but no one seems to know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are other questions that ask similar questions, this was taken from them:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Adding this `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the manifest was the only thing that significantly improved the performance for me