# WebView slow on loading content

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-alertdialog, phonegap-plugins

I am doing a custom dialog plugin for PhoneGap in Android. The Notification plugin for PhoneGap cannot set text in HTML format in dialog boxes. So I decided to make my own using WebView. But I noticed that when the Alert.Dialog appears, the WebView is initially empty and then the content is loaded a split second later causing the dialog height to "jump". Even when I hardcode the content passed to loadData, the loading of content is still slow.

Is there anything I'm missing?

```
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    try {
        JSONObject jo = args.getJSONObject(0);
        showCustomDialog(jo.getString("title"), jo.getString("message"), jo.getString("buttonLabel")); 
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

private void showCustomDialog(final String dialogTitle, final String dialogMessage, final String dialogButtonLabel) {           

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {                         
            WebView webView = new WebView(ctx);
            webView.loadData(dialogMessage, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);           
        alert.setView(view)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle(dialogTitle)
            .setPositiveButton(dialogButtonLabel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            )
            .show();
        }
    };
    this.ctx.runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```

Comment: Yes, PhoneGap 1.3. But their navigator.notification.alert and navigator.notification.confirm methods don't allow HTML in message.

Comment: I made a change to the code by setting setWebViewClient and moving the Alert.Dialog code inside onPageFinished event. That somehow made the loading of the WebView content a bit faster but there is still a noticeable delay. If you want to see this in action, the app is available on the Android Market. I'm not sure if I can post the link here, though.

Comment: Since no one seems to know the answer or might not have seen the actual behavior, I thought seeing the issue in action might help. Just search for "tower of hanoi noypiscripter" on Android Market and install on your device. Thank you.